How to mark the first up bar candle after a down bar candle
I'm new to Pine Script. I would like to mark the first up bar candle after the last down bar candle in a series of candles.
// UpBar Candle
UpBar = high> high[1] and low > low[1]
 
//DownBar Candle
DownBar = high < high[1] and low < low[1]  

UpBar1 = not UpBar[1] and UpBar
plotchar(UpBar1, color=color.blue)

Here is the problem

only applied to previous candle
it skipped some of the first upbar candle

How do I identify the last down bar candle and disregard any candles that come after except the first up bar candle and mark it? And how do I repeat the process for the entire series of candles?

What is an up candle? Just a green candle?

Sorry I messed up the code.  I have edited the actual code in the question.

To mark the first up bar candle after the last down bar candle in a series of candles in Pine Script, you'll need to keep track of the state of the market (whether it's in a downtrend or uptrend) and then mark the first up bar candle after the last down bar candle.
indicator("First Up Bar After Last Down Bar", overlay=true)

var bool uptrend = na
var bool downtrend = na

UpBar = high > high[1] and low > low[1]
 
DownBar = high < high[1] and low < low[1]  

// Here we can check if a new trend has started
if (not downtrend and DownBar)
    downtrend := true
    uptrend := false
if (not uptrend and UpBar)
    downtrend := false
    uptrend := true

// Mark the first up bar candle after the last down bar candle
firstUpAfterDown = na
if (uptrend)
    firstUpAfterDown := UpBar and downtrend[1]

plotshape(firstUpAfterDown, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, size=size.small)

Here I made the initial state of the market as neither in an uptrend nor downtrend na. Then, it checks for new trends starting based on the appearance of down or up bars. When it detects the start of an uptrend, it marks the first up bar candle after the last down bar candle. Hope this helps.
Edit :
If you want to identify the first up bar after a down bar regardless of the market trend and without considering the previous state of the trend, you can simplify the script. Now you don't have to track the trend state. You can directly check for the condition of the first up bar after a down bar.
indicator("First Up Bar After Last Down Bar", overlay=true)

// UpBar Candle
UpBar = high > high[1] and low > low[1]
 
// DownBar Candle
DownBar = high < high[1] and low < low[1]  

// Check for the first up bar after a down bar
firstUpAfterDown = na
if (DownBar[1] and UpBar)
    firstUpAfterDown := true

plotshape(firstUpAfterDown, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, size=size.small)

This simplified code can directly check if the current candle is an up bar and the previous candle is a down bar. If it's true, then it marks the current candle as the first up bar after a down bar, regardless of the market trend or the previous state of the trend.
New Edit
indicator("First Up Bar After Last Down Bar", overlay=true)

// UpBar Candle
UpBar = high > high[1] and low > low[1]
 
// DownBar Candle
DownBar = high < high[1] and low < low[1]  

var bool shapePlotted = na

firstUpAfterDown = DownBar[1] and UpBar
if (firstUpAfterDown and not shapePlotted)
    shapePlotted := true
else
    shapePlotted := na

plotshape(firstUpAfterDown, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, size=size.small)

Now, the script should plot a blue triangle below the first up bar after each down bar. The shapePlotted variable ensures that only the first occurrence is marked, and subsequent occurrences are ignored.

Thank you that help me a lot. But what if I just want to know the first Up bar after a down bar regardless the market trend?  I have mark the up bar and down bar candle with bar color and I only need the first up bar to be mark so I can continue towards writing other indicator to my script. I think the one that confuse is the use of var bool to identify the last down bar and also to identify the first upbar.

I made a edit so you can see how you can do that

it seem there is a problem with this line 'firstUpAfterDown = na' , it shows 'value with NA type cannot be assigned to a variable that was defined without type keyword'.

Sorry about that, in Pine Script version 4 and later, variables must be explicitly typed. All you have to do is define the bool variable. var bool firstUpAfterDown = na Now firstUpAfterDown is defined as a boolean variable, and it will be assigned true if the condition is met or na otherwise.

Im sorry to ask again, but it plot all the candles. I think i might miss out something here.

Sorry what did you miss?

the script plot all the candles (every candles) not the first up bar candles only . Thats why i think i might missing out something.

I fixed it again so it works. If this answer was helpful you can mark it as a accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the point score of the question.
